# Disable order email in Django-oscar

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-oscar

I built a simple e-commerce site with django-oscar.

After a successful order placement an email is sent to client regardless of settings. I found the code located at  `oscar/apps/customer/utils.py:Dispatcher.dispatch_order_messages`

Is it possible to turn this behavior off?

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot close-topic-overflow guys. @mevius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should fork the `checkout` app (as described [here](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/topics/customisation.html#fork-the-oscar-app)) and override the `handle_successful_order` method of the `OrderPlacementMixin`. You can copy the code from the oscar app and simply comment out the line where the confirmation message is sent.

```
# self.send_confirmation_message(order, self.communication_type_code)
```

Comment: I also checked source code, looks like its the only way. Thanks mate for answering this before clever guys close this question.

Comment: Cheers! Yeah there is no simpler way that does not include breaking oscar's emails sending altogether. I guess you needed to fork the checkout anyway to solve your pay-on-arrival issue ;-)